# Make and edit .psd file in iPhone file system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, adobe

I was wondering what the easiest way to make a .psd file from within an iPhone app. I am making an app just like the [Layers](http://www.layersforiphone.com/) app, and I can't fiure out how he makes and edits .psd files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not legal to make commercial program that uses psd files, its a proprietary format of Adobe. (you can make a deal with them, as a lot of companies do when they need to use a proprietary format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=7k961l1nk9vs0iogflnkgvl7t4#iOS). There's an iOS compiled binary that you can link into your application. Or if you want, you can set up the compilation business yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Writing a psd parser yourself is a futile business. See the super-famous quote from [here](http://fallenpegasus.livejournal.com/854615.html) ([original source code](http://code.google.com/p/xee/source/browse/XeePhotoshopLoader.m#108))

```
            // At this point, I'd like to take a moment to speak to you about the Adobe PSD format.
            // PSD is not a good format. PSD is not even a bad format. Calling it such would be an
            // insult to other bad formats, such as PCX or JPEG. No, PSD is an abysmal format. Having
            // worked on this code for several weeks now, my hate for PSD has grown to a raging fire
            // that burns with the fierce passion of a million suns.
```

It goes on and on. So, look for an (open-source) psd reading/writing library.

Comment: I almost downvoted, considering your answer funny, but not very helpful... until I saw that you actually did link to relevant source code :D

Comment: I do have to say: I couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the Layers app the OP mentioned. Unfortunately, coneybeare is right - I pretty much wrote an objective-c implementation from scratch. The trick turned out to be basing it off a very old version of the PSD spec, from before it got insanely polluted with crap. Layers actually writes Photoshop 3 files.

UPDATE: I've published the PSDWriter from Layers on github. You can use it to write PSD files from a set of UIImages on iOS or Mac OS X: https://github.com/bengotow/PSDWriter

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

They probably looked up the [spec](http://www.fileformat.info/format/psd/index.dir) for the `psd` format, then figured out how to write it manually.