# View psd file in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, view, psd

Is there any way to view PSD file in Objective-C (iPhone/iPad)? just view it as an image, no edit or change anything, just view the file. I searched but still not find out any positive solution.

Anyone know about this pls help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the following link which is same as your question

[Make and edit .psd file in iPhone file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762026/make-and-edit-psd-file-in-iphone-file-system)